# Библиотека для работы с протоколом WebDAV

Tags: c#, delphi, .net, библиотеки

Здравствуйте. Нужна библиотечка для работы с протоколом WebDAV, что то на подобии Synapse (это библиотека для Delphi) для C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Топ-5 из запроса https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=c%23+webdav&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

http://www.independentsoft.com/webdav/index.html (платная)

http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-webdav.php?referer1=google&referer2=adwords_webdav_net&gclid=CJPN-KmJ-bECFUJU4godBl0Akw

https://github.com/kvdb/WebDAVClient

http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav/

http://www.webdavsystem.com/server

Пробуйте.